# Python Relative File Importing

Tags: python-3.x, file-import

First off I want to apologize if this question has been posted numerous times, but the solutions I have been reading such as ([python relative import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863929/python-relative-import)) haven't really answered the question I am about to ask (or rather I don't understand how to apply this answer to my scenario). So basically I have two folders: AR and CL. In AR there is a file named "Around.py" and in CL there is a file called "Clear.py". How would I go about importing "Around.py" into "Clear.py".

[image]

NOTE: Assume I cannot use absolute paths as a solution (so please don't use them in the solution), but relative path importing is OK.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If the AR and CL folders are in the same folder, then the below should work for you from Clear.py:

```
from ..AR import Around
```

Comment: I get this error: ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Comment: Add `__init__.py` files in your AR and CL folders so that Python knows that they are modules.

Comment: Just add a file in those folders named `__init__.py` ? And I assume the file should be empty?

Comment: Yes, add the empty `__init__.py` files.

Comment: How are you executing your script ?

Comment: The Python IDLE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177315/discussion-between-shashank-verma-and-j-c).